# Starting the Motion Service Automatically on Boot

Tags: motion

I'm using the motion library on a raspberry pi zero with sketch.

In order to get the motion server to start on boot,  've updated /etc/rc.local to include the following:

```
sudo motion -c ~/.motion/motion.conf &
```

I'm having an issue with starting motion on boot. When I boot, I execute

```
ps aux | grep motion.conf
```

and see the following:

```
root 550  0.0  0.7   7212  2956 pts/0    S+   14:30   0:00  sudo motion -c /home/pi/.motion/motion.conf

root 554 23.1  7.5 137524 28680 pts/0    Sl+  14:30   3:13 motion -c /home/pi/.motion/motion.conf 

pi 595  0.0  0.4   4336  1660 pts/1    S+   14:44   0:00 grep --color=auto motion.conf*
```

If I kill -9 the first two processes, I'm able to successfully execute

```
sudo motion -c ~/.motion/motion.conf
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apparently, motion is started. Why do you need to kill it and start it again?

Comment: Don't use `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local`.  It's at best superfluous.  If you need to test it, use `sudo /etc/rc.local` instead.

Comment: Paste in the output from `ps -lC motion`, and, for each process listed, the output from `ps -lp NNN`, where NNN is the PPID (not PID).

Comment: Thanks @Dirk, When I boot the pi and check "sudo service motion" it shows motion as "active (exited)", and checking the media dir no images are being created. So I kill the processes and run "sudo motion -c ~/.motion/motion.conf" and motion works correctly.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks, here's the output of the two commands: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -lC motion
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0   554   550 14  80   0 - 34492 -      ?        03:05:14 motion
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -lp 550
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0   550     1  0  80   0 -  1803 -      ?        00:00:00 sudo

Comment: @JacobBlankenship Looks like you trying it twice. To test: remove it from rc.local, reboot and then check the status with systemctl

Comment: Okay so this time there was only one `motion` running, not surprisingly the child of `sudo` from your script.  You need to try that next time you see two of them to find out where the other one is from.

Answer (score 2):

Since version *Jessie* Raspbian comes with *systemd* that replaces classic *SysV* init process. *rc.local* belongs to *SysV*. To be compatible *systemd* tries to emulate classic *SysV* but with many limitations. Look at [systemd - Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/) what you have to take attention for when using *rc.local*. Better you switch over to *systemd* and start your services with a unit. A simple unit for your program could look like this but I don't know if there are some edge conditions you have to configure. By default it runs as root. Maybe you have to set `User=pi` on section [Service]?

```
[Unit]
Wants=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/motion -c /home/pi/.motion/motion.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Motion is automatically started at boot if you have installed it as a service (apt-get install method), if you compiled and built - what you are doing is correct.
But essentially if just used regular way of installing motion, you are creating two processes of motion at boot by adding it to rc.local.